Defacto rule to use both Simplified and Traditional Chinese in Chinese Language SE
大家好 (Hello everyone),
I am a non-Native Chinese speaker, who only knows Simplified version of the language as I learned the language in mainland China. I hope there might be my fellow non-Native Chinese speakers, who learned the language outside mainland China, and have trouble tracing back from traditional to simplified. I often resort to Google Translate or other sources to find the simplified equivalent when a character is written in traditional Chinese. Can we make it a habit in this community to use both variants wherever possible? It might help correlating and learning both versions of the language.

While your suggestion has a sound base, it does not constitute a "question". Rather than fully rely on Google or other translation apps, I suggest using an online dictionary, such as "漢(汉)典 -https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E6%BC%A2", which, in my opinion, is a much better learning tool.

This question is suited for the Meta version of the site.
I don't think it's a great idea. If you're interesting in picking up Traditional Chinese characters - it shouldn't be too much extra effort if you're already comfortable with Simplified. The only way that there would be two versions is if the translations happened to be different, i.e.: TW vs. Mainland (which you can see differently translated on some product overviews.)

You may not be aware, but not too long ago we had a non-Native Chinese teacher, (forgot his name), who encouraged his students to come to this Site to gain further knowledge of the Chinese language, complaining that some Posters posted in Traditional Characters thus causing problems for his students. You just cannot make everyone happy :) Given that Simplified Characters are the default version in most parts of the World, Traditional Characters are now of historical interest only. Even Hong Kong, the former bastion of Traditional Characters is succumbing, leaving only Taiwan to soldier on.

不同意，这基本属于浪费时间。回答的人在这里自愿回答初学者的问题，这种花时间的事情显然应该由受益者，也就是看回答的人来承担。很多时候我写一篇回答不仅要有中文还要有英文，现在你让我中文的部分还要输入两遍？恕难从命。

I don't think this is a good idea...

Simplified vs. traditional is not simply changing the character set; if we insist on people using both, we're going to end up with errors (especially in the simplified -> traditional direction).

The characters also give context, e.g., if a student is using simplified characters, you can get an idea of what study materials they've used.

Most people are far more proficient at one than the other, so insisting they use both adds an obstacle to posting ("ah, it's not worth posting this [question/answer/comment]").  It adds more work.  I don't even know how to input traditional characters.

It wouldn't make the problem go away, it just palms it off onto other people (they too will copy/paste from Google Translate).

What should we do if someone does not post in both simplified and traditional characters?  Delete their post?  Edit it in personally?  Nag them in comments?  Users who want to use both already can.  If users don't want to add both, it seems unreasonable to enforce it.

I, for one, carefully select what to include and exclude from my posts; and insisting on using both simplified and traditional would cause imbalance and lower my posts' quality.


If you post a question, you can indicate what you are and aren't familiar with.
I use a browser popup dictionary to help me with unfamiliar traditional characters; that works well enough for me.  I haven't tried these, but there seem to be browser extensions like this and this which can convert between simplified and traditional.

"I don't even know how to input traditional characters." As a serious and dedicated student, you'll probably get around to figuring it out eventually.

@goPlayerJuggler I don't agree. They are just different writing systems. Almost no native speaker needs to learn both. Learning either well is enough for one to master the Chinese language for communication purpose.

@王博龙 I didn't say she needed to learn both. I just mentioned inputting characters. IMO even if you only use simplified characters, some knowledge of traditional characters is almost indispensable if you aim to reach a high level of proficiency.


Can we make it a habit in this community to use both variants wherever possible?

it implied that people need to write in traditional chinese & simplified chinese together, just for other’s easier reading
it’s not an easy task
very often, terms in traditional chinese are different from simplified chinese, eg
the suicide squad,  it’s name in chinese is varied according to region
in mainland china: X特遣队：全员集结 (simplified chinese)
in singapore, malaysia: 自杀突击队：集结 (simplified chinese)
in hong kong, macau: 自殺特攻 (traditional chinese)
in taiwan: 自殺突擊隊：集結 (traditional chinese)
isn’t it tedious, to find the proper terms, put them together?
isn’t it an laborious for the writer?

Thank you for the answer and I totally get your point. But I think there is a minor thing in my post that is probably overlooked. As I now highlighted as well, I wrote "wherever possible". Of course it is not applicable to the cases you mentioned.

@NaveedAhmed, “wherever possible”  well, the applicable range is quite “narrow”, imo. terms translated from foreign language, particularly, texts before 1911, calligraphy, seal must be according to traditional chinese  so, as a reader, pay attention to, and, work hard, to comprehend traditional chinese characters, it you like the culture

Your comment reminded me of this chinese phrase 好好学习-天天向上 . ^_^

Two more reasons not to do this:

In answers relating to modern Chinese, it doesn't add any extra information to the answer.
For readers which have the knowledge or tools to switch between the two, it's the equivalent of writing English answers in both American and British English - this translates to more visual distractions, and more text to maintain.
For readers which are getting to grips with Chinese, sorry - but you're expected to know both eventually, so you'll have to get used to efficiently employing tools to help you.

In answers relating to older Chinese varieties, it's inappropriate to quote or give answers in characters that isn't what the source material was written in.



Your question is sound from a learner standpoint, but not actually reasonable from the language standpoint.
The direct equivalent would be asking all british people and american people to write both of each other's different spelling and word choice standards for every comment on here, to make it easier for the native chinese to read the english posts.
Not only do very few english speakers actively know both standards to type them at will, once you reach a certain proficiency you have no issue reading 99% of either-- native speaker or otherwise.  So is the case for chinese.
I cannot type simplified.  If it is clearly someone who is the most beginner of beginner, I will go out of the way to copy paste the simplified version for them, if only to avoid the confusion of them not inderstanding what traditional is.  However I can read entire books in simplified chinese no problem.  The passive intake is much much much easier when it comes to these things. Again just like I have no idea what british people call various things around the kitchen when actively asked about it, but I passively understand just fine when watching a british cooking show.
I say this only from the most purely logical point of view: it makes more sense for you to continue to learn chinese and eventually reach the proficiency level needed to read both, and therefore no longer need to copy and paste.  The alternative you are suggesting is for everyone at a proficiency level to read both to start copy and pasting, which is not a very sound concept.
